# WPF Application Ribbon crash

Tags: c#, .net, ribbon-control

I created a program in visual studio 2008 with multiple windows. One of the windows uses the windows ribbon control. Now the program works fine on my computer (windows XP) but when I want to run it on another computer fresh installed with .net 3.5 SP1 installed I can start the program but I get a crash when I open the window with the ribbon control. 
This is the error file I get when I do try catch:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.  Error at object
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding'. --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND)    at
>   Standard.HRESULT.ThrowIfFailed(String message)    at
>   Standard.NativeMethods.GetCurrentThemeName(String& themeFileName,
>   String& color, String& size)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemParameters2._InitializeThemeInfo()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemParameters2..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemParameters2.get_Current()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj, Object[] index)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetStaticExtensionValue(Int16
>   memberId)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetExtensionValue(IOptimizedMarkupExtension
>   optimizedMarkupExtensionRecord, String propertyName)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TemplateBamlRecordReader.ReadPropertyWithExtensionRecord(BamlPropertyWithExtensionRecord
>   bamlPropertyRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String
>   message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32
>   linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds,
>   XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext
>   parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message,
>   Exception innerException)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TemplateBamlRecordReader.ReadNonContentRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TemplateBamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean
>   singleRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TemplateTreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
>   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlTemplateSerializer.ConvertBamlToObject(BamlRecordReader
>   reader, BamlRecord bamlRecord, ParserContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord
>   bamlElementRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElement(Int64
>   startPosition, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Object
>   dictionaryKey)    at
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(Int32 valuePosition,
>   Object key)    at
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.RealizeDeferContent(Object key,
>   Object& value, Boolean& canCache)    at
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(Object key,
>   Boolean& canCache)    at
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(Object key, Boolean&
>   canCache)    at
>   System.Windows.DeferredThemeResourceReference.GetValue(BaseValueSourceInternal
>   valueSource)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.get_NewValue()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d,
>   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject
>   fo, DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject
>   container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents,
>   FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1&
>   newContainerDependents)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoThemeStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement
>   fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldThemeStyle, Style
>   newThemeStyle, Style style)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateThemeStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe,
>   FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldThemeStyle, Style newThemeStyle,
>   Style& themeStyleCache)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnThemeStyleChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, Object oldValue, Object newValue)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe,
>   FrameworkContentElement fce)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EndInit()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.EndInit()    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ElementEndInit(Object& element)
>   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementEndRecord(Boolean
>   fromNestedBamlRecordReader)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord
>   bamlRecord)    at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean
>   singleRecord)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at
>   Waak.WeegschaalProgramma.WeegAuteurWindow.InitializeComponent()    at
>   Waak.WeegschaalProgramma.WeegAuteurWindow..ctor(WeegschaalProcessor
>   weegschaalProcessor)

Anybody has seen this error before or has any tips to help me out? I already removed .net and completely reinstalled it.

Comment: Reinstalling .NET won't work. There is a binding issue somewhere in the XAML.

Comment: The problem is that the application works on my development computer but not on the computer I want to install the program.

Comment: Ah, sorry - have you installed the ribbon (or deployed it) on the other machine? I don't believe it's part of the core WPF in .NET 3.5

Comment: I installed the same version of the ribbon on the other machine. (Microsoft Ribbon for WPF october 2010 (version 4.0.0...). Is this a problem that I use this version on visual studio 2008 .net 3.5?
I still get the problem after I installed this. Also checked my language packs for .net and I installed the one's I had on my development machine on the other machine.

Comment: The only thing that solved my problem was redo the userinterface without the ribbon interface :(. If anybody ever has an answer to this problem post it here. It might be usefull for somebody else

Comment: Hello Pieter, I'm having exactly the same problem... Have you found a solution? Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Sorry no solution found, I didnt use the ribbon bar in the project cause I could not find the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is a bit different than the one I had (XamlParseException Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception.) but I think you should take a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777335/428494)